# Row Number doesn't match with Line count in unix. How is it possible?

Tags: shell, csv

I have a large csv file 'test.csv' whose line count is:

```
$ wc -l test.csv
2154868
```

Whereas if I count the first column in that file which is a date column, its count is:

```
$ cat test.csv | grep -w "2021-06-04" | wc -l
2154855
```

The datecode field is never empty due to query and is same throughout. So how can the line counts be so different?

Sample File data:

```
DATECODE|SKUCODE|SUPPLIERCODE|SUP_NAME|PRIMARY_SUPPLIER_IND|IS_VPN|IS_DIFFCODE|IS_DIFF_DIFFCODE|IS02_DIFF03_DIFFCODE|IS_DIFF04_DIFFCODE
2021-06-04|106|02971|AAAAA, INC.|Y|58730|2X (2X)|20MM (20MM)|SILVER (SILVER)|GLOSS (GLOSS)
2021-06-04|119|02080|BBBB|Y|CI400||||
2021-06-04|1194|02080|BBBB|Y|AT419||||
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `grep -vw "2021-06-04" test.csv` to see the lines that are being filtered out.